# Deploying config.php file with varibles using bitbucket pipeline repo varibles

Tags: php, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Is there a way to use bitbucket pipeline repository variables inside a config.php file when we generate a build using a pipeline?

example:
let's say in bitbucket repo we have $TWITTER_ID defined as "123456"
and in config.php file, we need to use this value of TWITTER_ID.

I came across serverless and lambda, but it's mainly for nodeJS.

Any other way to do this?